# Create and store element thought jqueryajax request and rails controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this code that is invoked when I press a button:

```
function senddingInfo() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/products",
    type: "POST",
    data: { "product": { "title": "aaaaaa", "description": "asdasdasdasd" } }  });

}
```

And I have this controller:

```
def create
    render plain: params[:product].inspect
end
```

I want to store the product info thought jquery ajax requests, but I don't know exactly how. What am I doing wrong?
I'm trying to render the values that arrive at the controller, but I'm getting nothing.
I'm new at rails so this must be simples, but I don't know how to do it.

**Edited:**
 I have made some changes in the code that are reflected above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are requiring :product which does not exist in the params you are sending to the controller. Either change the product_params to `params.permit(:name, :price)`(remove the require) or change mydata to `{product: { 'name': 'marioproduct', 'price': '99' }}`.

BTW, I am not sure if this is your finished code, but you might want to define success and failure handlers in your ajax call or your frontend wont know if the request it sent succeeded or not.

Comment: Thanks @AOG! I have made some changes, but still not working.

Comment: What do you see in the logs? If rails logs show nothing, then it might be a frontend issue and you might not be sending anything to the server